# Netrw multiple files selection

Tags: netrw

Is there a way to select multiple files not one by one (with `mf`)?

- I can see in the docs `:MF` command that do nothing for me. (`:MF *.vim`)
- I also have tried `mr` supplying it `*.vim$` in the folder full of vim files -- nothing happens

Or they do not work in windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had a time to check netrw code.

Looks like there is either a bug for a windows or just a bug (because it also doesn't work on my WSL debian).

The code in question is in function `s:NetrwMarkFiles(islocal,...)` on line `6660`:

```
fun! s:NetrwMarkFiles(islocal,...)
"  call Dfunc("s:NetrwMarkFiles(islocal=".a:islocal."...) a:0=".a:0)
  let curdir = s:NetrwGetCurdir(a:islocal)
  let i      = 1
  while i <= a:0
   if a:islocal
    if v:version > 704 || (v:version == 704 && has("patch656"))
     let mffiles= glob(fnameescape(a:{i}),0,1,1)
    else
     let mffiles= glob(fnameescape(a:{i}),0,1)
    endif
   else
    let mffiles= [a:{i}]
   endif
"   call Decho("mffiles".string(mffiles),'~'.expand("<slnum>"))
   for mffile in mffiles
"    call Decho("mffile<".mffile.">",'~'.expand("<slnum>"))
    call s:NetrwMarkFile(a:islocal,mffile)
   endfor
   let i= i + 1
  endwhile
"  call Dret("s:NetrwMarkFiles")
endfun
```

There is `fnameescape` function used to provide parameter to `glob` function:

```
    if v:version > 704 || (v:version == 704 && has("patch656"))
     let mffiles= glob(fnameescape(a:{i}),0,1,1)
    else
     let mffiles= glob(fnameescape(a:{i}),0,1)
    endif
```

and it effectively escapes `*` in `*.vim` parameter so you can't select all `.vim` files.

```
fnameescape({string})                   *fnameescape()*
        Escape {string} for use as file name command argument.  All
        characters that have a special meaning, such as '%' and '|'
        are escaped with a backslash.
        For most systems the characters escaped are
--->    " \t\n*?[{`$\\%#'\"|!<".  For systems where a backslash
        appears in a filename, it depends on the value of 'isfname'.
```

And on the other hand netrw Help:

```
    * One may use the :MF command, which takes a list of
      files (for local directories, the list may include
      wildcards -- see |glob()|) >

        :MF *.c
```

Which is kind of fails due to escaping.

Not sure where it should be reported -- vim github or directly to Charles Campbel.

PS, reported https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5239

Answer (score 1):

Please try v1671 of netrw from my website.  I agree that the fnameescape() should not be there: http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW

Comment: I have donwloaded vimball and I can see the same `fnameescape` there.